# Why there is no output for python -m site under virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm having a bit of trouble tracking this. When I execute 'python -m site' when I'm not under virtualenv I get a nice output with my sys.path directories listed and other stuff. When I switch to virtualenv there's no output. I briefly looked at the code under https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/develop/virtualenv.py and I can see virtualenv creates it's own site.py - but this module still has the `__main__` hook, and when I import it from interpreter and call whatever get's executed under `if __name__ == '__main__'` it works. What is the difference when I try to execute it via `-m` switch?

Answer (score 0):

I was somewhat interested this question. So i did few hacks.

First, i have changed **site.py** in python library directory by inserting `print(__name__)` line. Result was

```
$ python -m site
site
```

Next, i have added file mymodule.py into library folder with single line `print(__name__)`. Now result was

```
$ python -m mymodule
site
__main__
```

So it seems the **site** module is importing before `python -m site` command will run this module as script. When it's imporing again for script execution, python omits secondary import.